# No such device grub rescue, tried many solution

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, boot-repair

I have tried to bootrepair, which gave me error this:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda1
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install.real: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install.real: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is  discouraged..
grub-install.real: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Then I tried this solution from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036730 post number 2:

But when I do grub-install I get this error:

> Installing for i386-pc platform.
>
> grub-install.real: error: install device isn't specified.

I'm trying a lot but there is no way I could get grub working...

EDIT: This is the Boot-repair log:
http://paste2.org/0XAfAUzG

Comment: You install grub2's boot loader to the MBR of a drive like sda, not to a partition like sda1. So your command is wrong, you mount sda1 and install grub to sda. And why is sda1 ext2? Only if a smaller /boot partition might we use ext2, but ext4 is the standard for Ubuntu. And if you have a separate /boot partition you have to mount both / (root) and /boot before installing to sda. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Comment: I didn't use ext2... I don't know why that's there. And how do I mount to "sda1" and install grub to "sda".

Comment: Link above shows the detailed command, you just have to change the generic sdXY and sdX to correct drive like sda1 and sda. You can also use Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I did that, and I also used Boot-Repair... did you even read my question?

Comment: then post link to the summary report from Boot-Repair so we can see details.

Comment: @oldfred oke, updated.

Comment: Either you convert install to UEFI by adding efi partition or create the bios_grub partition so grub can install correctly. With gpt partitioning you have to have one or the other. And efi partition is for UEFI boot and bios_grub is so grub will install to protective MBR and boot in BIOS mode. You did boot Boot-Repair in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ESP (EFI partition, see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_partition) ), then run Boot-Repair again.

Comment: Is it normal that "Purge kernels then reinstall last kernel" take more than 30min on a SSD? It is still going... I don't know if it's stuck or not.

Comment: Oke it was stuck, and I had no improvements at all...

Comment: Can you please tell me which partition should get the Boot-flag? The EFI one or the main one?

Comment: put the boot flag on the EFI one.